# Batch Script Redirection Syntax

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I wrote an answer one day with a batch script example and someone pointed out that it's easier to read echo'd logic in batch scripts, when you're redirecting the output to a file, if you redirect to the file first and then put your command, text, etc. (below examples<sup>**[1]**</sup>).

This suggestion didn't mention any reason why you'd not want to do this though so I started investigating a little as I'm always looking for native methods to keep things looking a little cleaner.

---

> **Example Usual Way**
>
> ```
> IF EXIST "%tmpfile%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpfile%"
> ECHO Some Text Here>>"%tmpfile%"
> ECHO A little more text here>>"%tmpfile%"
> ECHO Some other text over here man>>"%tmpfile%"
> ECHO Can Scooby please have a Scooby snack>>"%tmpfile%"
> ```
>
> **Example Easier to Read Way**
>
> ```
> IF EXIST "%tmpfile%" DEL /Q /F "%tmpfile%"
> ECHO>>"%tmpfile%" Some Text Here
> ECHO>>"%tmpfile%" A little more text here
> ECHO>>"%tmpfile%" Some other text over here man
> ECHO>>"%tmpfile%" Can Scooby please have a Scooby snack
> ```

Obviously it is much **easier** to read logic from batch scripts with `ECHO` commands in this format but there would be a concern if there are any gotchas using this method as a standard in batch scripts.

I looked around on the Internet some and the most I was able to find was the one referenced source below stating to ***not use this technique in command lines that also contain other redirections***<sup>**[2]**</sup>.

---

### Question

*This question may be for Windows batch scripting experts or someone that has used this method for some time or that has done rigorous testing, but. . .*

1. other than the one issue (multiple redirects<sup>**[2]**</sup>) to not use this syntax, are there any other issues, reasons, or gotchas that you should be considered beforehand?

---

### References

- > ### [Redirection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)<sup>[1]</sup>
  >
  > - NOTES: (3)
  >
  >   Redirections to one or more files tend to make batch files hard to
  >     read. Sometimes the lines can be padded with spaces to align all
  >     redirection signs and make the batch file more readable.
  >
  >   However, if you were to do this with ECHO command lines, the spaces
  >     would really be ECHOed, which is not always convenient, to say the
  >     least.
  >
  >   On [Marc Stern's web site](http://xset.tripod.com/tip8.htm) I found a
  >     great solution: just place the redirections before the actual
  >     commands.
  >
  >   Take this imaginary batch file, for example:
  >
  >   `ECHO Directory of all files on C: >> LOG1.LOG`
  >
  >   `DIR C:\ /S >> LOG1.LOG`
  >
  >   Not exactly easy on the eye, that one?
  >
  >   How about this one, then?
  >
  >   `>> LOG1.LOG ECHO Directory of all files on C:`
  >
  >   `>> LOG1.LOG DIR C:\ /S`
  >
  >   It will do exactly the same, no difference! Much better, isn't it? But
  >     now, try these:
  >
  >   `VER | TIME > LOG1.LOG` `> LOG1.LOG VER | TIME`
  >
  >   As you will notice, in the second line, it is the output of VER that
  >     gets redirected to LOG1.LOG !! As a rule of thumb: do not use this
  >     technique in command lines that also contain other redirections.
  >
  > <sub>[source](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)</sub>

Comment: Why are you deleting `"%tmpfile%"` immediately after writing to it? You might as well not bother with the `echo`'s :)

Comment: @DavidPostill I took the other logic out of the examples that would run before that but good point.

Comment: Please note that "easier to read" is not related to "easier to figure out". What you described works, but it is a pretty obscure feature, I wouldn't use it because it will likely confuse other people reading your script. Other than that and what you already pointed out I know no other problems with it. I'd recommend @David Postrill 's answer, failing that - just align text with TABs or spaces - that's not a great solution but at least not a confusing one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### I'm always looking for native methods to keep things looking a little cleaner.

Here's another alternative, that (to me) is even more readable:

```
(
ECHO Some Text Here
ECHO A little more text here
ECHO Some other text over here man
ECHO Can Scooby please have a Scooby snack
)>>"%tmpfile%"
```

It's also more maintainable, since it is much easier to turn on/off the redirection if needed as it is done in one place.