# Task scheduler on Idle: Starts, but does not Stop

Tags: windows, windows-task-scheduler

[image: settings]

I am trying to get this .bat to run when idle (which it does) - however, it does not close when it ceases to be idle despite that checkbox being checked.

Any idea why?

Comment: What is the task exactly? If you execute a batch file, the Task Scheduler executes the batch and it's done with it's process from its perspective. Knowing how you scheduled the task, what it does, etc. may be important to troubleshoot this. See the https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 again for some tips that might help.