# when I use TaskschedulerR package why doesn't my R Script save the csv file.?

Tags: command-line, csv, r

I have a R Script that uses `write.csv` to create a CSV file.

This works fine when I run it from the command line, but no file is created when I run the script using TaskschedulerR. Why would it let me do this on command line but not when I use TaskschedulerR package?

The rest of the script runs with Scheduler, just not the CSV file saving part.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you certain that it is not creating the csv file? Could it be creating it but not in the location you expect? If you are using a relative filepath it could be creating the file relative to the task schedulers path rather than your script path, try using a full path for your output.

Comment: Look over the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 and this should help you troubleshoot why Task Scheduler is not executing or giving the expected result but there are various factors to consider but that post gives some good starting points, etc. for troubleshooting so look it over when you get a chance.