# Move multiple files from subfolders to one folder using CMD or Batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have files in subfolders which are in a folder structure is like this:

```
D:\Folder_Source  
D:\Folder_Source\file1.txt  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderA  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderA\file1.txt  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderA\file2.txt  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderB  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderB\file3.txt  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderB\file4.txt  
D:\Folder_Source\FolderB\file8.txt
```

I want to move some `txt` files in each subfolder to **`C:\Destination\`** from a command prompt.

For example, the files I want to move are `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, `file8.txt`, etc.

If there is a file in the destination folder with the same name of the file from the source folder being copied, I want to **keep both files and not overwrite the existing file**.

I tried this which fails and does not give me the expected result:

> `move /s file1.txt file2.txt file8.txt C:\Destination`

Is something like this even possible from command line or a batch script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a batch script and set three variables in it with one being the ***path to the root source directory*** which will be traversed for specific files, the second being ***the destination path*** where the new files will be copied, and the third being a ***file list of the file names you wish to copy*** to the destination directory.

With these three variables you can use a [`FOR /R`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop to traverse the source location and use conditional [`IF`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic to check whether or not files already exist for whatever copy or delete operation needs to be performed with each file. Furthermore you can use a [`CALL`](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) and [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to pass the parts of the file name to another routine and use additional `IF` logic along with [`SET /A`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to increment the duplicate file number, etc.

---

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "source=C:\Folder_Source"
SET "dest=C:\Destination"
SET "FileList=file1.txt file2.txt file8.txt" 

SET "dupCnt=1"

FOR /R "%source%" %%A IN (%FileList%) DO (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%%~NXA" (
        XCOPY /F /Y "%%~FA" "%dest%\" && IF EXIST "%%~FA" DEL /Q /F "%%~FA"
    ) ELSE (
        CALL :DupeRoutine "%%~FA" "%%~NA" "%%~XA"
        )
    )
GOTO :EOF

:DupeRoutine
IF EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" (
    SET /A dupCnt=%dupCnt%+1
    CALL :DupeRoutine "%~1" "%~2" "%~3"
) ELSE (
    IF NOT EXIST "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~1" "%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3" && DEL /Q /F "%~1"
    SET "dupCnt=1" 
    )
GOTO :EOF
```

---

### Results

> **Note:** If you wish for the duplicate file names to use another naming convention than the `_(#)` I used then you will need to
>   change the `_(%dupCnt%)` in the script within
>   `"%dest%\%~2_(%dupCnt%)%~3"` to be whatever other format you wish to
>   use but `%dupCnt%` is the number that will increment. I'm happy to help further with this too.

**Source Before**

```
D:\Folder_Source
│   file1.txt
│   file2.txt
│   file4.txt
│   file8.txt
│   file99.txt
│
├───FolderA
│       file1.txt
│       file2.txt
│       file4.txt
│       file8.txt
│       file99.txt
│
└───FolderB
        file1.txt
        file2.txt
        file4.txt
        file8.txt
        file99.txt
```

**Destination After**

```
C:\Destination
    file1.txt
    file1_(1).txt
    file1_(2).txt
    file2.txt
    file2_(1).txt
    file2_(2).txt
    file8.txt
    file8_(1).txt
    file8_(2).txt
```

**Source After**

```
D:\Folder_Source
│   file4.txt
│   file99.txt
│
├───FolderA
│       file4.txt
│       file99.txt
│
└───FolderB
        file4.txt
        file99.txt
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /R](https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html)
- [IF](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)
- [DEL](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html)
- [CALL](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html)
- **Batch Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [SET](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

  > **Arithmetic expressions (SET /a)**
  >
  > Placing expressions in "quotes" is optional for simple arithmetic but
  >   required for any expression using logical operators.
  >
  > Any `SET /A` calculation that returns a fractional result will be
  >   rounded down to the nearest whole integer.
  >
  > The expression to be evaluated can include the following operators:
  >
  > `+   Add                set /a "_num=_num+5"`

Comment: @LutfiCreativesys I used a combination of `XCOPY` & `DEL` rather than `MOVE` since I could put some validation conditional logic in with that command too. Also note that when you move, files will retain NTFS ACL attributes whereas when you use `XCOPY` it inherits the ACL attributes from the location which the files are copied. Typically you want to handle file security at a folder level so that is another reason I prefer `XCOPY` over `MOVE` although I used `Robocopy` a lot too, I usually don't keep dupes like this though either. Let me know if I can adjust further to accommodate your needs.

Comment: Nice answer guy 

Comment: lol regrettably, currently doing Telco contracting. Looking for full-time I.T employment.

Comment: why when I enter a file list of more than 500, the script doesn't work?

Comment: Does the script have limits on move files?

Comment: @LutfiCreativesys It's likely a batch limit but I'm not sure without researching it. You could try having two smaller arrays maybe and iterate those within another loop one after the other perhaps. Or use a filelist from a file as I wrote about in this answer https://superuser.com/questions/1267964/a-cmd-batch-for-f-command-that-will-not-open-a-text-file/1269852#1269852 where the text file contains the list of file you want to copy or whatever. Smells like justification for you to start a new question potentially for a more definitive answer. Q&A power to the rescue!!