# How to assign SeSymbolicLinkPrivilege to a user by command line?

Tags: windows, permissions, symbolic-link

How can I assign a user the SeSymbolicLinkPrivilege (permission to create symbolic links) through a command line script? Ideally with just cmd and without the use of PowerShell.

Comment: Run the script with elevated privileges (ie as an Admin).

Comment: I don't know how to perform this action with a script which is why I asked the question.

Comment: It is not an action you perform with a script in the script logic but a matter of something you need to do for the mechanism that is going to execute the script. If you have a script you execute manually, simply right-click run as administrator, otherwise I have some other ideas but you need to explain how you intend on running this once the script it setup? Are you no running it manually or else what do you intend to use to execute it as you need to exactly?

Comment: The script will be run either through a right-click run as administrator or from an elevated command prompt. The issue isn't on invoking administrative rights but rather my not knowing how to assign this privilege exclusively through a non-interactive script.

Comment: I'm not executing anything right now as I don't have any script yet. My question is asking for a sequence of commands that will assign the permission via a cmd or powershell.

Comment: Okay, use the options listed in my answer here https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 for #'s 1-3 then perhaps to schedule the process to execute with Task Scheduler to be assured elevation isn't also required at command execution. I have screen shots showing the options to choose as well but it should be as simple as that and simple to test. You could also have this job defined and disabled in Task Scheduler and then execute it via command line as-needed via `SCHTASKS /Run ~` (`SCHTASKS /?`).

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding. I don't need instructions on how to run an elevated script. I don't how to assign the `SeSymbolicLinkPrivilege` permission non-interactively (such as through a script) to a user.