# Task Scheduler failure Event IDs

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I am trying to monitor task scheduler using an monitoring application and i need the list of all the EventIDs that gets logged in the event viewer in case of failure.

Appreciate if someone can provide me the EventIDs

Comment: Yes, failure events under Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational

Comment: Read over my answer here too when you get a chance as it contains some good info you may find helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125.  Additionally, have you look over this post: https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2014/05/15/task-scheduler-event-ids/ and done research on those to verify accuracy yet? Maybe a good starting point.