# Batch file runs manually but not through Windows 10 Task Scheduler(Selenium script)

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, task-scheduler

I really need help getting a `.bat` file to run from the **Task Scheduler**.

- It runs when ran from location manually or when `Run` is clicked from **Task Scheduler**.
- It doesn't run on a schedule when `Run only when user is logged on` / `Run when user is logged on or not`
- The user is my local account is also the admin
- The `.bat` file is stored in `C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc\`, and this is what I have filled in for the `Program/Script` under Settings in `Actions` tab.
- I have unchecked all options under the `Conditions` tab, (tried checking the power options, still didn't work).

I'd would prefer to have the option set: `Run when user is logged on or not`.

**Question:** Is there something I'm missing or that I have setup or configured wrong that is causing this script to not run on the scheduled task?

---

**The .bat file code**

```
cd C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc
set ProjectPath=C:\Users\user1\eclipse-workspace\abc
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Lib\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
pause
```

Comment: Does the batch file perform any network specific tasks to mapped network shares? If so, remember to add the mappings in your script, because when you run whether the user is logged in or not, it will not run as your user but as SYSTEM user, and that means the login script is not run, so no network shares were made.

Comment: When you set the task to run when the user is not logged in, the operating system sets the working directory to system32 when task scheduler launches the script.

Comment: @Squashman, so whats your resolution on this?

Comment: @LPChip can you please tell me how can i add the mappings? This is my code :

Comment: @Test
 public static void currFetch() throws InterruptedException, FileNotFoundException {
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.com");
 }}

Comment: Don't post your code in comments. Edit your question. Your code does not look line a Windows batch-file so I am not sure why you are using that tag.

Comment: question edited

Comment: Gina - Read over my post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 for some helpful tips that may assist you in resolving this as well or at a minimum otherwise give you some additional things to try and/or eliminate if you've not already.

Comment: unfortunately @PimpJuiceIT that didnt work.

Comment: Hi Gina - My next suggestion would be for you to right click on the scheduled task and select the "export" option and then save that to an XML file. Then open that XML file where you saved it to with a text editor such as notepad and then copy the contents of it, and then [edit] your post and add this detail to your post. Feel free to mask out any sensitive information you feel should not be disclosed if you want and use `*****` or some dummy value in its place if you want and feel it's sensitive. This may help us see something being overlooked potentially and is very easy and simple.