# Task Scheduler- Batch "Run whether user is logged on or not" not working

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I've created a batch file (`EnableDisable.bat`) that will disable a **Windows** **Task Scheduler** job (`SampleJob`) on a local system,  if a job with same name (`SampleJob`) is already enabled and running on another remote system.

It seems that when the job is setup with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option checked along with `Run with Highest privileges` that it just doesn't work and the reason is hard to determine and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

---

### Batch File

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('schtasks /Query /S [servername] /TN "SampleJob" /NH ^| findstr "Ready ^| Running"') do schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "%%j"
```

> **Note:** The remote system is referred to as [`servername`] and will be replaced by the actual remote server name where needed.

---

### Windows Task Scheduler Job Configurations

- This batch file is configured as a Windows Task Scheduler job

  - **Name**: `EnableDisableJob`
  - **Security Option**: `Run whether user is logged on or not`

    - `Run with Highest privileges`

---

### Observations

If I run the job with the `Run only when user is logged on` it seems to work just fine without any issue. However, it seems like when I try to run it with the other option, and because that account is not logged on, it cannot run when that is the case.

---

### Question

How do I troubleshoot this sort of issue and where should I start to begin that process?

Comment: I have a similr problem. https://superuser.com/questions/1418031/cannot-run-batch-in-task-scheduler-when-security-optons-set-to-run-whether-user Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To troubleshoot this here are a few things**

1. Logoff the machine you run this process as with the `User1` account
   and then log onto the machine as the `User2` account and ensure a
   profile gets built for `User2`. So the `C:\Users\User2` folder should exist.
2. While you are logged onto that machine as `User2` run
   the scheduled task or at least test it with `Run only when user is logged on` and `Run with highest privileges` and this should pop up the command
   prompt window when it runs and show any errors, etc. which you wouldn't see running it with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` option. If you see an "access denied" error or something of that nature, then there's a permission issue.

**Permission Issue**

You will want to ensure the user account you run the **Task Scheduler** scheduled job with the `Run whether user is logged on or not` and `Run with highest privileges` has access to. . .

1. run command prompt (`cmd.exe`) from the machine you run the task on
2. run `schtasks` from the machine you run the task on
3. run `schtasks` remotely against the remote server you run the task against

**Other Items**

1. Make the `User2` account a local admin on the machine you run the task on temporarily and then logoff and back onto the machine and and try again to rule that out local machine permission issues.
2. Compare the security differences with the `User1` and `User2` on remote
   machine, domain security groups, etc. as well.

---

### Further Resources

- [Windows 10: Scheduled tasks with workstation lock/unlock not being triggered](https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125)

Answer (score 2):

All suggestions above from Pimp Juice IT are great. I'll mention one other thing here.

You have to make sure the user account running the task has `Log on as batch job` user rights. Here's the doc from MS: [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-batch-job) .

And here's a link on how to set this from Local Security Policy: [link](https://www.gfi.com/support/products/how-do-i-configure-an-user-account-to-have-logon-as-a-service-permissions) .

You can also do this via GPO.

Of course, as Pimp Juice IT suggested, if the user is already a Local Admin, they may already have this right.

Comment: This is done automatically when registering the scheduled task, as documented by Microsoft [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/log-on-as-a-batch-job), which is the very same link you posted. Also at that link, it's documented how to alter that default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure the two folders exist below, otherwise it will not work:**

I tried all of the solutions above and nothing worked. If you want to run whether the user is logged on or not, then you need to ensure that the two folders added below, otherwise it will not work based.

- Create "Desktop" directory in Elevated CMD (important) or File Explorer in

  **C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop**

  **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop****

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/c03d6691-b058-4f8d-961c-e8eba25bbaed/task-scheduler-problem-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not?forum=w7itprogeneral

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with running a bat file to backup some databases, even though the user was admin and had `Logon as batch job` permission, which started after update to Windows 11 22H2. What worked for me was ticking the checkbox `Do not store password. The task will only have access to local computer resources.`. Honestly, have no idea why this helps, but I'd assume that this is because the account I was using is not a "local" one, but MS one, so maybe some new restrictions were added to help with security.