# How to run wsl using Task Scheduler without loging?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

According to [Task Scheduler- Batch "Run whether user is logged on or not" not working](https://superuser.com/questions/1334931/task-scheduler-batch-run-whether-user-is-logged-on-or-not-not-working) and other articles, "Run whether user is logged on or not" requires pure batch processing without interactive and UI.

How to run a wsl2 program on system start?
I have tried use `wsl -e ...` and `wsl --shell-type none`

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Do you require user interaction? Or don't you, but somehow it doesn't work? And if the latter, what is the error message?

Comment: @LPChip I'm sorry if I made it confusing. I don't need interaction, I just want to run the batch before user login. There is no error message, the only hint is that when manually run the task, Task Scheduler immediately reports the batch exit with code 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is the subject of bug-report
[Unable to start WSL via Task Scheduler #8835](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/8835)
from Sep 19, 2022, and running up to almost today.

There are several listed workarounds for the problem that
you could try. The one that worked for more than one user
was to use a non-Store distribution - the Store versions
seem unable to start with
"Run whether user is logged on or not".

There are other solutions, some using
[PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec),
that you may find in this bug-report.

Comment: The reason why I must run it as a user rather than system is because the whole WSL image is inside the user. As a result all programs inside that WSL image can only be executed in context of that user. Could you please tell me whether I am right about this?

Comment: Do the WSL programs work only on WSL files, or also on Windows files outside of WSL?

Comment: For me I work only on WSL files, but I would also like to know the difference

Comment: In such a case, the WSL user account has no relation to the Windows account. A standard Windows user may login as root to the WSL distribution.

Comment: Well, actually, the WSL distribution is installed user-wide, and the whole Linux system disk (`ext4.vhdx`) is in user's %LocalAppData%. In fact if another user type `wsl` in terminal, an error message will show up, saying there is no installed distribution for WSL.

Comment: That's another problem. See [link](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/2979).