# Unable to run batch starting Excel as scheduled task

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, command-line, batch, scheduled-tasks

I have the following Skript that was previously run manually:

```
set DIR="X:\SYSTEM\MAKROS"
X:
cd %DIR%
start /wait EXCEL.EXE /e-GENERATE_REPORTS BSYSTEM.XLA
```

When manually started, this works just fine. The `BSYSTEM.XLA` is part of an Excel-Based project management system, so I cannot export the file to a different file format.

I now need to run this script on a daily basis. When creating a scheduled task to run this `.bat`-file it simly doesn't work. The task ends whithin several seconds (the script normally takes about 10 minutes to complete) with the last run result code `0x1` and the history of the task doesn't show anything helpful:
[image]

I've already tried to create a task that directly runs `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /e-GENERATE_REPORTS BSYSTEM.XLA` but this just errors out with this being shown in the history:

> Task Scheduler failed to launch action "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" in instance
>   "{1fbeadd0-605b-4fe0-8d96-621281c53519}" of task "\Allgemein\TMG
>   Bericht". Additional Data: Error Value: 2147942667.

I've also tried a vbs script like this:

```
set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\SYSTEM\MAKROS\BSYSTEM.XLA")
xlApp.Run "GENERATE_REPORTS"
xlBook.Close
xlApp.Quit
```

But this way I get the error `The macro can not be executed. The 'GENERATE_REPORTS' macro may not be available in this workgroup, or all macros have been disabled`, which is not true since its working fine with the obove script being called manually. The network drive from which the file is strated is set as a "trusted location".

Strangely enough when I open `BSYSTEM.XLA` I don't see any sheets, just an excel file with mostly all elemnts greyed out except the makro button and when trying to take a look at the macros I dont see any. Thats why I'm struggling to understand what `start /wait EXCEL.EXE /e-GENERATE_REPORTS BSYSTEM.XLA` even does..

I couldn't really find anything helpful about Excel command line switches except these two documents:

- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6
- https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/291288/description-of-the-startup-switches-for-excel

What can I do to provide a scriptable alternative to the above btach script so that I can run this command as a scheduled task, or what can I do to fix the vbs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since with this command Excel needs to display a UI the task is unable to run in the Background which is automatically the case when `Run whether user is logged on or not` is selected in the task properties.
After setting this option everything worked as expected:

[image]

For the Task to be able to be executed after a restart of the server I enabled automatic login with [this tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/autologon).

Answer (score 2):

Your VBA script is failing because xlBook is not the correct object to support the Run method.

**Try**

```
xlApp.Run "GENERATE_REPORTS"
```

Alternatives to above

- If your macro is in a module `xlApp.Run "BSYSTEM.xls!GENERATE_REPORTS"` 
  'notice the format of 'workbookName'!macro
- If your macro is in a sheet `'xlApp.Run "'BSYSTEM.xls'!sheet1.GENERATE_REPORT"`

**File Extensions**

**.xla** is an Excel Add-In file format, you could try saving it as an **.xlam** which is a macro-enabled format of xla.

**Code Breakdown**

`set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")` '[Creates the Excel Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/createobject-function) process.

`xlApp.Visible = True` 'Enables the [application to be viewed/edited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-visible-property-excel).

`set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("X:\SYSTEM\MAKROS\BSYSTEM.XLA")` '[Opens a specified workbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbooks-open-method-excel) within the Excel Application that was just opened.

`xlApp.Run "GENERATE_REPORTS"` '[Runs the macro command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-run-method-excel) GENERATE_REPORTS.

`xlBook.Close` 'Closes the workbook.

`xlApp.Quit` 'Ends the Excel Application Process.

Comment: This gets me one step further: The error I now get is: `The macro can not be executed. The 'GENERATE_REPORTS' macro may not be available in this workgroup, or all macros have been disabled.`

Comment: @farosch Read over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389562/cannot-run-the-macro-the-macro-may-not-be-available-in-this-workbook for help with the next for multiple solutions to that error.

Comment: @farosch is your [macro in a module or in one of the sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232777/1690180)? Also worth checking the following link on [how to enable macros in office files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-12b036fd-d140-4e74-b45e-16fed1a7e5c6).

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT All settings in the trust center are set. When being manually called via the batch script it works, so this cant be the problem. Also added this info to my question

Comment: @angelofdev I don't see any sheets when opening the `BSYSTEM.XLA`, just an Excel file with all elements greyed out. The macro overviw doesn't show any macros either.. I also added this Info to the initial question

Comment: @farosch I wanted to mention that if task scheduler is running the batch under a different security context that you type in the credential when you save the job and not the same credential as the user that's logged on which you set those "trust center" settings, then you will want to sign onto that machine as that account and set those trust settings with its account by the way. See https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 for further tips with task scheduler just in case too.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT just checked: I am logged in as our domain service user kue\service and the task is running as the same user also.