# Taskschd.msc -.bat won't write to file

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

Have a .bat file set to run at logon in taskschd.msc.

Have confirmed that it runs at logon (.bat and window appears).

However, it isn't writing to the .txt file as one of its functions.

It works fine when run manually but doesn't write data to the .txt when run at logon via taskschd.msc.

Any solutions to this issue?

Comment: What error message and how is the scheduled task set up?

Comment: Can you also provide the batch file, or at least the row that is supposed to write data to the .txt file?

Comment: Arianax - Read over my post here: https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125 and this will give you the basic and detailed steps to troubleshoot this problem; the answer will likely be within there somewhere since you states it works as expected when you run the same batch script manually.