# task scheduler doesn't seem to be running powershell script like it should

Tags: windows-10, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have the following PowerShell script saved as test.ps1:

```
# test script
Write-Output "z" >> C:\path\to\log.txt
```

In the Task Schedule I have it set to "*Run whether user is logged in or not*".

The trigger is "*One time*" but I have "*Repeat task every:*" checked and set to "*5 minutes*".

In the Actions tab I have one Action - "*Start a program*" that's set to "*powershell.exe*" with "*Add arguments (optional)*" set to "*-file c:\path\to\test.ps1*" and "*Start in (optional)*" set to "*c:\path\to*".

In the History tab I see:

> Task Scheduler launched action "powershell.exe" in instance "{a1485114-69fe-4aa8-95ee-27d8f260591a}" of task "\test".

So it looks like it's working to me but log.txt is neither being created or added to.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Task Scheduler PowerShell script not running

Based on what you describe you can make a few minor adjustments, and check a few other easy-to-overlook settings that can cause these same problems at times.

```
<Exec>
  <Command>Powershell</Command>
  <Arguments>-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\path\to\test.ps1"</Arguments>
</Exec>
```

From the **Action** tab you will create an **Action** defined as:

- **Action:** `Start a program`
- **Program/script:** `Powershell`
- **Add arguments (optional):** `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\path\to\test.ps1"`
- **Start in (optional):** `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`
  [image]

Also, some of these options in your case may help too, I'm not 100% they are needed but easy enough to test.

From the **General** tab of the scheduled task, be sure the **Run
whether user is logged on or not** and the **Run with highest
privileges** options are both selected.
[image]

Very importantly, be sure the **Start time** is the *exact time* you want the process to run the first time but of a *prior date* and then it'll run first starting only at that *time*.

Also consider using `Write-Output "z" | Out-File "C:\path\to\log.txt"` with or without the `-Append` parameter to redirect the output to the file in case that's the issue.

Lastly, from the **Settings** tab you might also *uncheck* the **Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed** as this can cause this problem as well. a *prior date* and then it'll run first starting only at that *time*.

### Further Troubleshooting

Since you are using the **Run whether user is logged on or not** option, you can log into the system with the credential which you run this job as when prompted and using that option.

Once logged on open cmd and then run `PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "c:\path\to\test.ps1"` and see what result or errors you get from there which might need resolved such as the account not having execute access to the ps1 script, etc.

### Additional Resources

- [Windows 10: Scheduled tasks with workstation lock/unlock not being triggered](https://superuser.com/questions/1214736/windows-10-scheduled-tasks-with-workstation-lock-unlock-not-being-triggered/1217125#1217125)
- [Task Scheduler](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page)

---

Comment: Just an FYI you can remove the "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass" arg if you set this globally:
Open Powershell in ADMIN (window MUST say Administrator"
cmd: powershell set-executionpolicy Bypass
(Im sure the security folks will have issue with this though)